# How to conditionally search data with many to many relationships with gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am developing an application that manages quotes using gorm.
Quotes have multiple tags.
When multiple tags are specified, I want to get quotes that includes all the specified tags.

This is my data model.

```
type Quote struct {
    ID        uint      `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
    Text      string    `json:"text"`
    Page      uint      `json:"page"`
    ISBN      string    `json:"isbn"`
    Tags      []Tag     `gorm:"many2many:quote_tags;" json:"tags"`
}

type Tag struct {
    ID        uint      `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    Name      string    `json:"name"`
}
```

I want to do something like this. (not grammatically correct)

```
db.Preload("Tags").Where(<quotes.tags.name contains all tagNames>).Find(&quotes) // tagNames []string
```

Is there a way to do this with gorm?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do in this situation is first find out what the SQL you'd need to run needs to look like.

For getting all the quotes matching all given tags you'd need to join your quotes table to a subquery that counts how many tags match for each quote, like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM quotes 
JOIN (
   SELECT quote_id, count(*) AS count
   FROM quote_tags qt JOIN tags t ON qt.tag_id = t.id
   WHERE t.name IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag4')
   GROUP BY quote_id
) AS matched ON quote_id = quotes.id AND matched.count = 3
```

Once you have that, you try to say this in Gorm:

```golang
requiredTags := []string{"tag1", "tag2", "tag3"}
db.Preload("Tags").
    Joins(
        "JOIN (?) AS matched ON quote_id = quotes.id AND matched.count = ?",
        db.Select("quote_id, count(*) AS count").
            Table("quote_tags qt").
            Joins("JOIN tags t ON qt.tag_id = t.id").
            Where("t.name IN (?)", requiredTags).
            Group("quote_id"),
        len(requiredTags),
    ).
    Find(&quotes)
```

See: [GORM Advanced Query/From Subquery](https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#From-SubQuery)

Comment: I got this error. `Request is failed: sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type gorm.DB, a struct[]` SQL and subquery are correctly working, so I think there is a problem in assigning the subquery to the JOIN clause.

Comment: Which version of gorm are you using? Make sure it's the latest stable version (or at least > 1.20, equivalent to >2.0)

Comment: I was using an older version of gorm. I updated from github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.16 to gorm.io/gorm v 1.21.9 and the above error disappered. Thank you for your helpful answer!